# Don't work onClick xml ? Android

Tags: android, android-xml

I have an `xml` that `handle onclick` in `xml` the `onClick of Button` working but `onClick TextView` don't work.

Bellow my `row_listview.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/row_cell_text_dummy_multilevel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/row_cell_btn_multilevel"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:onClick="CellButtonClick" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/row_cell_text_multilevel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="CellTextClick"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And bellow is my `StartActivity.class` :

```
public class StartActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    }

    public void CellTextClick(View v){
        try {
            Log.i("test", "OK");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            }
    }
}
```

Notice : my `android:onClick="CellButtonClick"` work good but my `android:onClick="CellTextClick"` don't work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have an `adapter` and in your `adapter` you have a `onclickListener` for your `TextView`(`android:id="@+id/row_cell_text_multilevel"`) if you have ! you should comment it then use from `android:onClick="CellButtonClick"`.

Answer (score 2):

try to `TextView`

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: my android:onClick="CellButtonClick" work good but my android:onClick="CellTextClick" don't work .

Answer (score 0):

Add this to textview android:clickable="true"

Comment: Is this a layout for list view items? If so, you could add the listener to ListView (setOnItemClickListener)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `android:clickable = "true"` under TextView  ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

and the following is the java code

```
public class test extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(test.this, "Textview Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

}

it working

Comment: and A.A you defined any text for Textview with id "@+id/row_cell_text_multilevel".. untill you dont define any text and you wont click on textview it will not work